# Users with most comments from Drupal + phpBB

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, phpbb

i need to get a list of users with mosts comments + posts from Drupal + phpBB.

I am using mySQL.

Structure of Drupal database:
dr_comments(cid,uid)
dr_users(uid,name)

phpBB:
phpbb_posts(post_id,poster_id)
phpbb_users(user_id,username)

I have SQL code for users with most comments from Drupal and phpBB not together.

Drupal:

```
SELECT
 U.name,
 COUNT(C.cid) AS CommentCount
FROM
 dr_users AS U
 INNER JOIN dr_comments AS C ON U.uid = C.uid
GROUP BY
 U.name
ORDER BY
 COUNT(C.cid) DESC

LIMIT 10
```

phpBB:

```
SELECT
 U.username,
 COUNT(C.post_id) AS CommentCount
FROM
 phpbb_users AS U
 INNER JOIN phpbb_posts AS C ON U.user_id = C.poster_id
GROUP BY
 U.username
ORDER BY
 COUNT(C.post_id) DESC

LIMIT 10
```

I dont know how to merge it together.

Comment: Please define *...merge it together...*. It might mean different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION:

```
SELECT name, SUM(CommentCount) AS TotalCommentCount
FROM (
  SELECT U.name, COUNT(C.cid) AS CommentCount
  FROM dr_users AS U
  INNER JOIN dr_comments AS C ON U.uid = C.uid
  GROUP BY U.name

  UNION ALL

  SELECT U2.username AS name, COUNT(C2.post_id) AS CommentCount
  FROM phpbb_users AS U2
  INNER JOIN phpbb_posts AS C2 ON U2.user_id = C2.poster_id
  GROUP BY U2.username

) temp GROUP BY name
```

That should do its job. Note for the script above I expect that the usernames are on both programmes equal.

You can also check this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ea0a/8/0)**.

Comment: It gives me error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Strange. As you can see in my liked fiddle it should work. I'll dig a little more.

Comment: OMG how stupid you just need to add a missing alias I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your *...merge them together...* can be interpreted in several ways. If you want to simply union both resultsets keeping order of each resultset intact then you can do

```sql
(
  SELECT u.name,
         COUNT(c.cid) CommentCount
    FROM dr_users u JOIN dr_comments c
      ON u.uid = c.uid
   GROUP BY u.name
   ORDER BY COUNT(c.cid) DESC
   LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT u.username,
         COUNT(C.post_id) CommentCount
    FROM phpbb_users u JOIN phpbb_posts c 
      ON u.user_id = c.poster_id
   GROUP BY u.username
   ORDER BY COUNT(c.post_id) DESC
   LIMIT 10
)
```

If you need to union both resultsets and then reorder them

```
(
  SELECT u.name,
         COUNT(c.cid) CommentCount
    FROM dr_users u  JOIN dr_comments c
      ON u.uid = c.uid
   GROUP BY u.name
   ORDER BY COUNT(c.cid) DESC
   LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT u.username,
         COUNT(C.post_id) CommentCount
    FROM phpbb_users u JOIN phpbb_posts c 
      ON u.user_id = c.poster_id
   GROUP BY u.username
   ORDER BY COUNT(c.post_id) DESC
   LIMIT 10
)
   ORDER BY CommentCount DESC
```

It also might be interpreted as get TOP 10 from both phpbb and drupal

```
SELECT name, COUNT(cid) CommentCount
  FROM
(
  SELECT u.name, c.cid
    FROM dr_users u  JOIN dr_comments c
      ON u.uid = c.uid
   UNION ALL
  SELECT u.username, c.post_id
    FROM phpbb_users u JOIN phpbb_posts c 
      ON u.user_id = c.poster_id
) q
   GROUP BY name
   ORDER BY CommentCount DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12010/11)** demo

Comment: Your example should fail due you have different column names.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Take a look at provided sqlfiddle.

Comment: I see, I did not know that union does not expect equal column names. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: You're welcome :) `UNION` will always take column names from first select and number and types of columns in subsequent selects should be the same as in the first select

Comment: It is TOP 10 :-). I am sorry for not being fully accurated.